# How to use CoreWebView2Frame Class in windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webview2

I have a windows webview2 application where we are automating 3rd party website with too many nested iframes and I want to execute javascript in a particular iframe. I want to know how get `CoreWebView2Frame` instance for the particular iframe using WebView2. Microsoft documentation didn't help.

I am looking for an example or a documentation to work with `CoreWebView2Frame` Class and shows how to execute javascript in a particular iframe by using `CoreWebView2Frame.ExecuteAsync()`.

I have gone throught the [this thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/948) but it's too difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a [`CoreWebView2Frame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2frame?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) by handling [`FrameCreated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#framecreated) event and use it later.

**Example:**

In the following example, the WebView2 browses [this Uri](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_test), then we find the iframe inside the page, and store it for later use. Later when the user clicks on a button on the WinForms app, using [`ExecuteScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2frame?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#executescriptasync) method of the iframe, we click on a link inside the iframe programmatically.

To do so, drop a WebView2 and a Button on the form. Handle Load event of the form and Click event of the button and modify the code like this:

```
//using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

CoreWebView2Frame sampleFrame;
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView21.Source = new Uri(
        "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_test");
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    webView21.CoreWebView2.FrameCreated += CoreWebView2_FrameCreated;
}
private void CoreWebView2_FrameCreated(object? sender, 
    CoreWebView2FrameCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Frame.Name == "iframeResult")
    {
        sampleFrame = e.Frame;
    }
}
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sampleFrame != null && sampleFrame.IsDestroyed() == 0)
    {
        await sampleFrame.ExecuteScriptAsync(
            "document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();");
    }
}
```

Now if you click on the button, the link which is inside the iframe will be clicked.

Comment: +1 for a helpful answer. Although it hasn't helped me to capture the contents of the particualar iframe that I'm after, it was educational and may be useful later.