# How do WebView execute the script exactly in the right frame?

Tags: c#, winforms, webview

I want to execute the "target" script in the "JCGameIFrame" frame. How to do it?

You need to implement layer selection as in DevTools:
[image: You need to implement layer selection as in DevTools]

This is how I tried to implement everything, but I don't know how to choose JCGameIFrame:
[image: my try]

Comment: You need to call [`ExecuteScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2frame?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#executescriptasync) or the right [`CoreWebView2Frame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2frame?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1462.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: Example: [How to use CoreWebView2Frame Class in windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74995289/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Can you help me with this? I changed a piece of code in the question. It doesn't work for some reason to implement this.
await doesn't work, replaced with "var task".